# Google SignIn not retaining credentials when relaunching App?

Tags: ios, google-signin, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Sheets API and Drive API and have migrated my App to use Google SignIn instead of embedded webView authentication.  I am able to successfully sign in the user and pass authentication to the API services, however whenever the app enters the background it doesn't retain the credentials.  Previously this code would just reload credentials from the keychain and refresh the tokens if need be instantly:

```
self.service.authorizer = 
           [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                 clientID:kClientID
                                 clientSecret:nil];
```

But now I need to check if credentials exist in the keychain using the following code in my AppDelegate:

```
if ([GIDSignIn sharedInstance].hasAuthInKeychain) {
    NSLog(@"Auth exists in keychain!");
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signInSilently];
} else {
    NSLog(@"No credentials in keychain!");
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
}
```

SignInSilently seems to take a while and I need to pause my code for 3 seconds before passing the credentials to my API services.  From the documentation it doesn't seem possible to just save and reload the credentials from the keychain anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I realised I wasn't using the Google SignIn callback method correctly.

```
(void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error
```

This method gets called once signin is complete and from here you can obtain credentials.  So I just moved signin out of my AppDelegate and into my viewcontroller and made my viewcontroller the delegate for `GIDSignInDelegate` and `GIDSignInUIDelegate` to receive the callback.  So now this viewcontroller is my startup screen to kickoff signin and then proceed once it completes therefore removing any static delays I had set.
Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Recently Google has changed the methods for checking if the user has been already loggedIn in Google SignIn SDK v5.0.0.

> Update calls to signInSilently and hasAuthInKeychain to
>   restorePreviousSignIn and hasPreviousSignIn.

So the code will look like

```
if(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasPreviousSignIn()) {

      GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()

  } else {

    navigateToLogin()

 }
```

Migration guide: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide